# Google Cloud Endpoints not working in Internet Explorer 8 - Javascript error

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, internet-explorer-8, google-cloud-endpoints

The code below is raising an error in Internet Explorer 8, this code is running inside a page called proxy.html loaded from /_ah/api/static/proxy.html

```
return window['googleapis']['server']['initWithPath'].call(this,document.getElementById('root').value
```

The javascript is saying:  "object required"

I think the element 'root' on page body is not loaded, but in other browsers this works.

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround for this problem? I'm seeing the same behaviour in internet explorer 10 as well.